# HTML tag with different attributes

Tags: html

How can I make a html tag having different attributes ? 
For example I want have something like this :

```
<div id="id1" description="description 1" cost="23" owner="me" date_of_purchase="1-1-2014">  first purchase </div>
```

thanks

Comment: Do you mean _custom_ attributes? Use [`data`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attributes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would use **[data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes)**.

So for example:

```
<div id="id1" data-description="description 1" data-cost="23" 
     data-owner="me" data-date_of_purchase="1-1-2014"> first purchase </div>
```

> data-* attributes allow us to store extra information on standard,
>   semantic HTML elements without other hacks such as classList,
>   non-standard attributes, extra properties on DOM, or setUserData.

Answer (score 1):

You can just do it like that.  But it will not validate.  HTML5 specifies the data-* attribute syntax which you can use for custom attributes which **will** validate and are perfectly OK to use.

So basically prefix your your custom attributes with

> data-

```
<div id="id1" data-description="description 1" data-cost="23" data-owner="me" data-date-of-purchase="1-1-2014">first purchase </div>
```